# React switch not switching

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-table

I've added a switch to a header of my react table and even when the state clearly changes, the swithc just does not switch, any ideas?

Here's the code:

```html
function DefaultParametersRowContent({ data, impactFields, onClickHandler, content }: any) {
  console.log(content);
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "",
        accessor: "name",
      },
      {
        Header: "",
        accessor: 'action2',
        type: "switch",
        Cell: (row: { row: { original: any; }; }) => (
          <span >
            <div className='menupolicy__form--switch'>
              <label className='switch'>
                <input
                  type='checkbox'
                  checked={content}
                  onChange={() => onClickHandler()} />
                <span className='switch__slider round'></span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </span>
        ),
      },
      {
        Header: () => null,
        id: 'expander',
        Cell: ({ row }: any) => (
          <span {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps()}>
            {row.isExpanded ? <FaChevronUp /> : <FaChevronDown />}
          </span>
        ),
      }
    ],
    []
  );
```

[And here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gojfS.png)

The logged bool is the value of consent, I've switched it multiple times and as you can see the state changes but not the switch itself

Comment: try to remove useMemo or add dependency in useMemo array

Comment: Yes!!! that was it! Thank you so much Raman!

Comment: How was this preventing the switch from working btw? I tried changing checked prop to value prop and it worked then but disabled the api call in the process

Comment: changing props lead to re-render component, but your columns was the same as before because of useMemo